# How to display the entire list of currencies?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to output the exchange rate given by the [ECB API](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?c892a2e0fae19504ef05028330310886). But the output shows an error

```
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"
```

How to fix this error?

```
import requests, config
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(config.ecb).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

course = soup.findAll("cube")
for i in course:
    for x in i("cube"):
        for y in x:
            print(y['currency'], y['rate'])
```

Comment: May be in here Y is a string then there is no key.

Comment: Just in addition - In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you have too many `for`-loops.

Comment: In case someone decides to go with the hardcoded choices field here are the list of currencies and countries as a Python tuple:[List of currencies and relevant countries](https://gist.github.com/mjallday/1141751/1e9bf44188bde49f4f6c3973b07c34766f22bb87) Credits: [Marshall Jones](https://github.com/mjallday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `for`-loops

```
for i in course:
    print(i['currency'], i['rate'])
```

But this need also to search `<cube>` with attribute `currency`

```
course = soup.findAll("cube", currency=True)

course = soup.findAll("cube", {"currenc": True})
```

or you would have to check if item has attribute `currency`

```
for i in course:
    if 'currency' in i.attrs:
        print(i['currency'], i['rate'])
```

---

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?c892a2e0fae19504ef05028330310886'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

course = soup.find_all("cube", currency=True)

for i in course:
    #print(i)
    print(i['currency'], i['rate'])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
r = requests.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?c892a2e0fae19504ef05028330310886').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
result = [{currency.get('currency'): currency.get('rate')} for currency in soup.find_all("cube", {'currency': True})]
print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'USD': '0.9954'}, {'JPY': '142.53'}, {'BGN': '1.9558'}, {'CZK': '24.497'}, {'DKK': '7.4366'}, {'GBP': '0.87400'}, {'HUF': '403.98'}, {'PLN': '4.7143'}, {'RON': '4.9238'}, {'SEK': '10.7541'}, {'CHF': '0.9579'}, {'ISK': '138.30'}, {'NOK': '10.1985'}, {'HRK': '7.5235'}, {'TRY': '18.1923'}, {'AUD': '1.4894'}, {'BRL': '5.2279'}, {'CAD': '1.3226'}, {'CNY': '6.9787'}, {'HKD': '7.8133'}, {'IDR': '14904.67'}, {'ILS': '3.4267'}, {'INR': '79.3605'}, {'KRW': '1383.58'}, {'MXN': '20.0028'}, {'MYR': '4.5141'}, {'NZD': '1.6717'}, {'PHP': '57.111'}, {'SGD': '1.4025'}, {'THB': '36.800'}, {'ZAR': '17.6004'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just in addition to answer from @Sergey K, that is on point how it should be done, to show what is the main issue.*

Main issue in your code is that, your selection is not that precise as it should be:

```
soup.findAll("cube")
```

This will also `find_all()` parent `<cube>` that do not have an attribute called `currency` or `rate` but much more decisive is that there are spaces in the markup in between nodes `BeautifulSoup` will turn those into `NavigableString's`.

Using the `index` to get the attribute values, won`t work while you do it with a` NavigableString`instead of the next``.

You can see this if you `print(y.name)` only:

```
None
Cube
None
Cube
...
```

> How to fix this error?

There are two approaches in my opinion

1. Best is already shwon https://stackoverflow.com/a/73756178/14460824 by Sergey K who used very precise arguments to `find_all()` specific elements.
2. While working with your code, is to implement an `if-statement` that checks, if the `tag.name` is equal to 'cube'. It is working fine, but I would recommend to use a more precise selection instead.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?c892a2e0fae19504ef05028330310886').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

soup.findAll("cube")

course = soup.findAll("cube")
for i in course:
    for x in i("cube"):
        for y in x:
            if y.name == 'cube':
                print(y['currency'], y['rate'])
```

##### Output

```
USD 0.9954
JPY 142.53
BGN 1.9558
CZK 24.497
DKK 7.4366
GBP 0.87400
HUF 403.98
PLN 4.7143
...
```